# Let $p(x)=x^3-6x-6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Find roots of $p(x)=x^3-6x-6$ using cubic formula

---

Quadratic Formula

$$ x^3 +ax^2 +bx+c=0$$

sub in $x=y-a/3$ to get

$$ y^3+py+1$$

where $$ \begin{aligned}
   p&=\frac{-a^2}{3}+b
\\ q&= \frac{2a^3}{27}-\frac{ab}{3}+c
\end{aligned}$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
   R&=\frac{1}{2}\left (-q + \sqrt{q^2+\frac{4 p^3}{27}}\right)
\\ S&= \frac{1}{2} \left ( -q -\sqrt{q^2 +4p^3/27}\right) 
\end{aligned}
 $$

and solutions of $z$ are
$$ z=R^{1/3}.R^{1/3} w ,R^{1/3} w^2 $$
and $$ z= S^{1/3},S^{1/3} w ,S^{1/3} w^2 $$

In this case
so  $a=0, b=-6,c=-6$ and $p=-6,q=-6$

getting that $R=-2$ and $S=-4$

From R

$$ z=(-2)^{1/3},(-2)^{1/3} w^1 , (-2)^{1/3} w^2$$

From S
$$ z=(-4)^{1/3},(-4)^{1/3} w^1 , (-4)^{1/3} w^2$$

guessing that $w$ is the root of unite for 3. I want to verify with Sage that these are indeed roots

I am not gettting that $(-2)^{1/3}$ is a root. Howell has  good section on this about tartaglia , Ferro .   on his intro on later sections. But dont have the book with me

Comment: You don't need to do the substitution as the equation is already in the format of $t^2 + ax + c = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define $z$ above.

$x^3 - 6x - 6 = 0$

let $x = z + \frac {2}{z}$

$z^3 + 6z + \frac {12}{z} + \frac {8}{z^3} - 6z - \frac {12}{z} - 6 = 0\\
z^3  - 6 + \frac {8}{z^3} = 0\\
z^6 - 6z^3 + 8 = 0\\
(z^3 - 4)(z^3 - 2) = 0$

if $z = 4^{\frac13}$ then $\frac {2}{z} = 2^{\frac 13}$

$x = 4^{\frac13} + 2^{\frac 13}$

i.e. you need both $R$ and $S$ above to find $x$... and you flipped your signs.

That takes care of the real root.

Then $\omega(4^{\frac13} + 2^{\frac 13})$ and $\omega^2(4^{\frac13} + 2^{\frac 13})$

Will be your complex roots.

And yes $\omega, \omega^2$ are the roots of $(x^2 + x + 1)$ i.e. roots of unity.